# Быстро оборачиваемый — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как правильно писать "быстро оборачиваемый" и "медленно оборачиваемый", если речь идет о товаре, например.

Comment: Написание может зависеть от контекста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Быстро оборачиваемый — слитно или раздельно?**

В академическом словаре Лопатина все подобные сочетания помечены звёздочкой. Это означает, что возможно как слитное написание сложного прилагательного, являющегося термином, так и раздельное написание слова с наречием.

Если Вы спрашиваете о названии группы товаров, тогда это термин и, следовательно, пишется слитно.

Comment: По сути, рынок периодики во многом является рынком **быстрооборачиваемых** товаров массового спроса (Fast Moving Consumer Goods) со всеми присущими этому рынку законами. [От совершенствования товара к интенсификации продаж (2002) // «Витрина читающей России», 2002.10.25]

Comment: Продовольственники-оптовики не смогут зарубежным поставщикам объяснить, почему **быстро оборачиваемый**, скоропортящийся товар долго не оплачивается. [Наталья ШАРАЙ ,Ольга АНТИПЕНКО. Мнение народного эксперта: Если валюта не появится, с импортом начнутся проблемы // Комсомольская правда, 2011.04.28]

Comment: Быстрее всего адаптировались те компании, которые работают в сфере **быстро оборачиваемых** товаров (например, торговля шоколадками, конфетами, бытовой химией, косметикой и так далее), и фармацевтический рынок. [Ольга АНТИПЕНКО. Топ-менеджеры иностранных компаний зарабатывают почти 10 тысяч долларов в месяц // Комсомольская правда, 2011.01.18]